# Updating multiple rows in a table within one SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table called `'PRODUCTS'` and I need to update this table when a sale is completed. Is there any way to combine all of the updates into one SQL statement?

Currently I have something like:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET PROD_Q=PROD_Q - 1
WHERE PROD_CODE='A'

UPDATE PRODUCT
SET PROD_Q=PROD_Q - 1
WHERE PROD_CODE='B'

...
```

Isn't there a more effective method of doing this?

Comment: Ummm... `update product set prod_q = prod_q - 1 where prod_code in ('A','B','C');` (or whatever)?

Comment: @sgeddes gave you a correct answer as long as you sell one of each product.  However, if you sell 1 of A and 2 of B, the separate queries are probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for -- using `IN`:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT 
SET PROD_Q=PROD_Q - 1
WHERE PROD_CODE IN ('A','B')
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
UPDATE PRODUCT SET PROD_Q=PROD_Q-1 WHERE PROD_CODE='A' OR PROD_CODE='B'
```

This will update for both the values of the prod_code